# What are the different qualities of the intervals?

Tags: chords, chord-theory, chord-progressions, intervals

I know that a 3rd decides the emotional quality of a chord, but what about the 5th? What does the 7th do? The 2nd, 6th, and 9th?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96753/discussion-on-question-by--what-are-the-different-qualities-of-the-interva).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image]You can ask the Greek or look up the theories of Boethius, Glarean, Caspar Printz, Ernst Kurth etc ... The answers will be more traditional than opinion based. But did you look up wikipedia under characteristics / qualities of intervals? I did and couldn’t find much information.

The key words are **psycological effects of harmonical intervals**

*The idea that the various musical intervals have widely disparate psychological effects has a long history in the literature of aesthetics, music theory and composition but not in experimental psychology*

http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.577.9997&rep=rep1&type=pdf

[image]

I used to present to my classes test sheets with a bi-polarity profile like below to get an statistical intersubjective information like they did here:

[image]

But I‘m doubting that these effects and impressions are intercultural representatives and objectives!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! It's weird that in the 2nd photo, they include both the aug. 4 and dim. 5.

Comment: Even in the second and third examples, the terms used are subjective - meaning different things to different people. Whilst the charts seem to have been produced in good faith, your closing comment has more than a ring of truth about it.

Comment: Is the Willems table supposed to apply to chords? minor triad: heavy emptiness, diminished triad: shadow instability. That doesn't make much sense. Surely the _emotion_ of music is more about the temporal aspects - the changing events - than the vertical stack of intervals.